# Python UnicodeDecodeError: ascii vs utf-8

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

Why the following code is still use "ascii" to decode the string.
Didn't I tell python to use "utf-8" to decode the string? Plus, 
how come `ignore` did not work?

```
print data.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
```

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 12355:

Comment: How you explicitly tell Python to handle a string does not affect what it does implicitly in order to print it.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I dont think its the print ... see my answer (I think its right... I dunno string encodings sometimes hang me up too)

Answer (score 3):

I assume data is a str

`print isinstance(data,str)`

should probably tell you true

`encode` wants a unicode so first it tries to `decode` your str to unicode using the ascii codec

hence why you get the `UnicodeDecodeError` not `UnicodeEncodeError`

try

```
print data.decode("utf-8","ignore")
```

Comment: And hence why Python 3 won't automatically convert byte strings to Unicode strings - you'll get a completely different error that is much easier to interpret.